# How to change for drawing Manager selection option by default?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, drawing

I use `google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager` that seems like:

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    markerOptions: {
        draggable: true,
        optimized: false,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('uxt/images/ap_gif.gif')
    },
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
        ]
    },

    polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#1E90FF',
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        editable: true
    },
    map: mapA
});
```

so my toolbar looks like:
[image]

As you see by default (after page reload) Marker is selected but i need "the hand" ('Stop drawing') to be selected.
[image]

How can I configure drawingManager to make this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just set `drawingMode` in options to `null`:

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: null,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with following code. if its not work then please check this post [Google Maps API v3: Drawing Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020407/google-maps-api-v3-drawing-manager) this might be helpfull

```
  var markers = [];
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
      if(event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
        alert("polyline complete");
      }
      else if(event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        var newMarker = event.overlay;
        newMarker.content = "marker #" + markers.length;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(this.content);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
        markers.push(newMarker);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't refer to my question. I need "hand" to be selected and not "marker" by default